# Get JPA credentials from external file

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

We have one web service for an app in our company. This app has several clients, in every client we have diferent database urls, usernames and passwords. Everytime I need to change the project and regenerate the .war file with maven I need to set the persistence.xml with every single credentials for each client.

Is there a way to setup a config file in tomcat for setting this configurations?

My persistence is like these:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user1" />
    roperty name="hibernate.connection.password" value="pass1" /> 
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://url1" 
/>
```

then a generate the .war and I have to change it again like this:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user2" />
    roperty name="hibernate.connection.password" value="pass2" /> 
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://url2" 
/>
```

then re generate the war. One for each cliente.

Using Enviroment variables is not possible since some of the clientes are using external services to host the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out my own answer:

First you will need to create the setenv.bat (or setenv.sh if on linux) and create your variables like this( on Windows):

```
set _URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
set _USERNAME=root
set _PASSWORD=root
```

this file is located in your tomcat folder /bin alongside with the startup.bat and shutdown.bat. Now when you start this server this varialbles will be available.

To use this variables in Java you need to everwrite then in your connection class like this:

```
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", System.getenv("_URL"));
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", System.getenv("_USERNAME"));
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", System.getenv("_PASSWORD"));
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("project", properties);
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: I think the first part, on Linux, can be done more efficiently by setting an environment variable file in the systemd unit - https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service